# django text links design

Tags: django

I have several paragraphs of text I want to put on my website (running on django). There is a link in this text every other sentence or so. What is the best design for how displaying this text?

Should the text reside in the template, the view function, or the database? Should the  tags be hard coded into the text, or should I have a table of urls/site names in the database?

I personally feel its nicer if everything is in the database. So I was thinking of writing a pseudo templating system where I store text like this in the database:

I'm asking a question  {{ "here", "stack overflow" }}

and then write a function that grabs all the tags and replaces them with the right html.

Does django already provide a convenient way to do this? Are there accepted conventions?

Comment: could you post how you plan to replace the text? how the link maps to the name? A custom template tag seems like it is worth looking into depending on what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping it simple unless you have a specific reason to involve your own templates, database lookups etc. and just go with writing html in your pages.

If you're determined to make life hard for yourself or you're trying to solve something more complicated than your question implies then something like [markdown](http://packages.python.org/django-markdown/) might help.